# Javascript link does not work when open in new tab or window

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have some link like this

```
<a href="#" onclick=aFunction(this)>link</a>
```

Where "aFunction" opens a link in the current window.

When this link is clicked, it is ok and opens the link, but if it is clicked as "open in new tab" or "open in new window", it does not work.

aFunction code is something like this:

```
aFunction(object)
{
   object.href = "www.mypage.com"
}
```

Comment: Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: I have tested in FF 3.5 and IE 7

Answer (score 1):

Using the context menu for "open in new X" does not trigger the click event. If your code is there simply to set the new window's address, then you'd be far better off doing

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com" target="_new">link</a>
```

instead. It won't validate, but it'll degrade better.

Comment: I cannot use the href parameter because "aFunction" can open different links depending of some conditions.

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out how to catch the "open in X" events in the various browsers. using javascript to manipulate links like this is a minefield - no matter how lucky you are, there's always one step that'll go boom.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do something like this instead of just putting the url in the href parameter?  You can still do other stuff on the click event if you want by adding a click handler even if you use the href attribute properly.

```
<a href="http://www.mypage.com">link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { // using jQuery for simplicity, but other methods work, too.
   $('a').click( function() {
        // do some other stuff
   });
});
</script>
```

Note that by not returning false (or using preventDefault()), we allow the normal click action to take place once our javascript has run.

Comment: I cannot use the href parameter because "aFunction" can open different links depending of some conditions.

Comment: @Torque - you could still give it a value so that it falls back to something useful in the absence of javascript.  Or perhaps, don't even use an anchor tag, just use a styled SPAN so the user doesn't have the option of "Open in ..."

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<a id="mylink" href="#">link</a>

<script>
function changeUrl()
{
   if( /* some condition here */ )
      document.getElementById('mylink').href = "www.someurl.com";
   else
      document.getElementById('mylink').href = "www.someotherurl.com";
}
</script>
```

In this way **the "Open link in a new tab" of the browser does not brake**.

If the condition changes when the user touches something on the page you need to call `changeUrl` whenever he touches something.

Answer (score -1):

Please find below a function to open url in new window:

```
function load() {
var load = window.open('http://www.domain.com','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');}
```